# A footstool with no legs is standing on its side. Is it correct to say "place / lay the stool down upright"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

We have this structure in [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lay_1?q=lay)

> **lay somebody/something + adj.**
>
> Eg, *The cloth should be laid flat.*

And "**[upright (an adjective)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upright_1?q=upright): placed in a vertical position**"

So, I think we can say "**lay the footstool upright**" but since the footstool is standing on its side, it's better to use the adverb "**down**".

It will become "**lay the footstool down upright**", but it sounds awkward.

Is it correct to say "**place / lay the stool down upright**"?

Comment: You answered your own question. Upright is awkward here because the footstool top is already upright  by the definition you provided so you don't need it.

Comment: @GWarner, so just, "lay the footstool down"?

Comment: Yes. Consider the many different uses and meanings of 'down'

Comment: You could also add a word: Lay/set it down flat.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, and "flat" in "Lay/set it down flat" is an adverb or an adjective?

Comment: @Tom I think the word "flat" is the same sort of word as "down", it just further qualifies it. i think both are "resultative adjectives", that describe a state resulting from an action, in this case, "laying".